# Laravel 6.2 on AWS elastic Beanstalk. Assets not loaded

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I have hosted a laravel 6.2 app on AWS elastic Beanstalk. Previously everything was working fine when the site was static, but after I created an RDS instance and made the site dynamic, the site still works fine, but the javascripts and css file I have kept inside the public folder are not being loaded.

First, I thought this might be something about the file permissions. So I made 'webapp' the owner of `public` folder and changed it's mode to `777`. The javascripts and css still wont load. No error is shown in the network tab of browser dev tool.

I do I go on and solve this. I am finding it hard to find an approach.

Here's a screenshot of the result of `ls -l` in the root directory of my app.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean that it changed from static to dynamic?

Comment: I mean I started using db connections and fetching data from tables to render the views.